# Pattern attribute on text input not working as intended on microsoft edge

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

use the following HTML code :

```
<input type="text" pattern="(((\d+)([-]{0,1})(\d+))*)" />
```

you can’t submit the form because Edge says that the format is incorrect even if the value matches the pattern (e.g: 123-123-1343).

It works in Firefox and Chrome but not in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/nuks06uc/

Comment: @NisargShah did you tested it on chrome?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Yes.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight this is just example im using the this 'pattern="(((\d+)([-]{0,1})(\d+))*)"' pattern and validating this value "123-123-1234" it works fine on chrome and firefox but doesnot on microft edge or internet explorer.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman This makes more sense. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: @NisargShah please test in on Microsoft edge

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Your previous pattern was working on Edge as well. But I can repro the problem with Edge with the pattern updated in your question.

Comment: Does regex `\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}` work for you? Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nuks06uc/2/

Comment: @NisargShah my regex is different it can indlude a single dashes '-' between numbers any where any time.

Answer (score 0):

I Just figured it out its not an issue on Microsoft edge's end. In fact Microsoft edge helped me detecting a bug where chrome and Mozilla failed. The issue was exactly in regular expression inside pattern attribute. i had to make correction in regular expression.

Now my code looks like this:

```
<input type="text" pattern="((\d+)(([-]{0,1})(\d+))*)" />
```

Note: Patter attribute does not work on Internet explorer 9 or earlier releases.

Thanks for help by the way.